# ADF Copy activity Sink Pre-copy script timeout

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pre-copy script `DELETE FROM mytable where ID=123`

This timed out (after 4 hours)

Then I gave `TRUNCATE TABLE mytable` and I got the error 'Table does not exist or no permission' .

I am able to insert from ADF copy. But on pre-copy or on lookup query . I get the errors state above. What could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

In Lookup active, your query `DELETE FROM mytable where ID=123` and `TRUNCATE TABLE mytable` doesn't return any result.

Please ref the [Look up active note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#supported-capabilities):

- **When you use query or stored procedure to lookup data, make sure to
  return one and exact one result set. Otherwise, Lookup activity
  fails.**

Just according the error message, please make sure you're using the user/account which have enough permission to delete the data in Sink linked server dataset.